# How to Configure VPN Client in Windows CE 6.0 Device

Tags: c#, windows-ce, vpn

I have WinCE 6.0 device with internet connection, I want to communicate this device using VPN. But i'm unable to configure VPN Client in the device. Is there any VPN Client software i need install on my device?? Please help me to proceed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with MOVIAN / ANTHA VPN Client for Windows CE..

[Movian/Antha Resouce Page](http://www.cites.illinois.edu/vpnarchive/movian-install.html)